# LED is HIGH if analogValue reached 500 5 times in 10 seconds. How?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to turn ON the LED if the value from potentiometer reached greater than 500 5 times in 10 seconds. Its been a week and i am stuck on this project. What i am trying to do is too difficult for beginner?

Demonstration: https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/317517042178589250

So far this is my code.

```
const int ledPin = 2;
const int analogPin = A0;
int PeakCount = 0;           
int lastPeakValue;

void setup() 
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode( ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
   int peakValue = analogRead( analogPin);

if( lastPeakValue < 500 && peakValue >= 500)
{

   PeakCount++;
   Serial.print( "Bark !  (");
   Serial.print( PeakCount);
   Serial.println( ")");
}
lastPeakValue = peakValue;
    
delay( 100);  
}
```

Comment: Any advice you can give? @gre_gor

Comment: Of course your sketch does not light a LED, but you could show the Serial.output you get...

Answer (score 0):

You need measure time. Depend on requested precision you can count yourself. One loop take 100ms, because you call

```
delay(100)
```

Or you can measure time by millis() function.